# What is resultant table name from INNER JOIN command on SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm creating a one to many table relationship and want to access information from the created table using the INNER JOIN function of SQLite. I just don't know how to go about it. I'm guessing I need to access the resultant table by its name but I don't know what it is called. Any ideas?

---

Lets say I have two tables

```
|TABLE_A       |         |TABLE_B                       |
|id    |name   |         |id    |foreign_id   |subjects |
|1     |Dave   |         |1     |1            |math     |
|2     |Steve  |         |2     |1            |science  |
|3     |Peeve  |         |3     |3            |english  |
```

And I use the code

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, t.subjects 
FROM TABLE_A u
INNER JOIN TABLE_B t ON u.id = t.foreign_id
```

And this should be the resultant table

```
|TABLE_?                 |
|id    |name   |subjects |
|1     |Dave   |math     |
|1     |Dave   |science  |
|3     |Peeve  |english  |
```

But what is this tables name? How do I access its information?

Comment: You want both data from tables TABLE_A and TABLE_B with inner join. So you want to output the data from this query to a new table that you create.. i.e. a view

Comment: Create a view for this query and u can access it further

Comment: A query result wouldn't have a table name by itself unless you coded it that way. Or perhaps your software has certain  requirements? Can you show a simpler example, how would you normally code a SQL query such as  "SELECT * FROM TABLE_A" in your software, and how do you usually store or display the result?

Comment: There is simply **no "resultant table"**, for your query ***as is***.

Comment: @clarity123 can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the SQL code in parenthesizes then add a synonym. Then using this synonym in the outer query as a table name.

```
(SELECT u.id, u.name, t.subjects 
FROM TABLE_A u
INNER JOIN TABLE_B t ON u.id = t.foreign_id) TABLE_X
```